# Is it possible to get and query element by dataset when using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dataset

we are all familiar with getElementByID, getElementsByClassName, and document.querySelector() methods. My question would be, as HTML5 allows us to use data-set now, can we query elements by their data-set? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dystroy's answer is probably exactly what you need. Additionally, query all the data-set might not be supported by all browsers. Instead, I create a class name that is similar (or identical) to the data-set name and use that as the anchor to query the elements.

Answer (score 6):

There's not a lot you can do but you can get the elements having a specific variable in dataset using :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name]');
```

and you can get elements having a specific value using

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="value"]');
```